# React Native with local push notifications,redux and headless js

Tags: react-native, push-notification, redux

I implemented HeadlessJS in my Android application and the application triggers my task as expected when i receive a notification from my Websocket Server.
My next task is to add new incoming notifications payloads to Redux Store  but the task js file is like this and I know to connect only components to the store.

The goal is to dispatch the incoming data in onNotification function and save it to redux.How to do it? Thank you!

```
import PushNotifications from 'react-native-push-notification';

module.exports = async (taskData) => {

  PushNotification.configure({

      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function (token) {
          console.log('TOKEN:', token);
      },

      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function (notification) {
          console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
      },

      // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
      // senderID: "YOUR GCM SENDER ID",

      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      permissions: {
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true
      },

      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,

      /**
       * (optional) default: true
       * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
       * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
       */
      requestPermissions: true,
  });


  PushNotifications.localNotification({

      id: taskData.conversation_id, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
      ticker: "Club Message", // (optional)
      autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
      imageUrl: 'https://uri/avatar.jpg',
      smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
      // bigText: "My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded", // (optional) default: "message" prop
      subText: "New message on Attraction App", // (optional) default: none
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
      vibration: 500, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
      tag: 'message', // (optional) add tag to message
      group: "group", // (optional) add group to message
      ongoing: false, // (optional) set whether this is an "ongoing" notification

      /* iOS only properties */
      alertAction: 'view',// (optional) default: view
      category: null,// (optional) default: null
      userInfo: null, // (optional) default: null (object containing additional notification data)

      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: taskData.username,
      message: 'Message: ' + taskData.message, // (required)
      playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
      soundName: 'default', // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
      // number: '10', // (optional) Valid 32 bit integer specified as string. default: none (Cannot be zero)
      repeatType: 'day', // (Android only) Repeating interval. Could be one of `week`, `day`, `hour`, `minute, `time`. If specified as time, it should be accompanied by one more parameter 'repeatTime` which should the number of milliseconds between each interval
      // actions: '["Yes", "No"]',  // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
  });

  console.log(taskData);
}
```